# How to filter list according to the value of text box

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, controller, partial-views

I'm newbie to asp.net and c#.

I need to filter a list according to a text box and display it in the webpage. So I did the following in controller.

```
 public PartialViewResult GetDetails (int id)
    {
        List<VoInfoDetail> model = db.VoInfoDetails.ToList();
        return PartialView("VoDetails", model);
    }
```

and I write in the view the following jQuery

```
function getdetails() {
            var id = $("#VoNo").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/VoInfoHeaders/GetDetails",
                type: "GET",
                data: { id: id },
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#VoDetails").html(data);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                }

            });
        }
```

How can I pass the parameter (id) from view to the partialview controller to filter the data according to that value. I already pass the (id) but it's not filtering

Comment: Change the method to `public PartialViewResult GetDetails (string id)` (or `int id` or what ever to match the type your passing)

Comment: I did and I edit the code but still is not working

Comment: You're not using the `id` in a `where` clause

Comment: What is not working?  The `id` parameter in the method will contain the value of the textbox which is what you asked!

Comment: @StephenMuecke he was actually asking about where condition but he didnt know how to apply on list

Comment: @StephenMuecke oh yeah my bad :P i didnt saw that

Comment: Thanks for all... I really don't how to use the functions of c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I already pass the (id) but it's not filtering

It's because you should write filtering logic by yourself, i.e:

```
public PartialViewResult GetDetails (int id)
{
    List<VoInfoDetail> model = db.VoInfoDetails
             .Where(x => x.Id == id)
             .ToList();
    return PartialView("VoDetails", model);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ... it's my fault. I thought I can write it like that 
List<VoInfoDetail> model = db.VoInfoDetails.ToList(id);

Answer (score 1):

Add id as a parameter to GetDetails, then alter your model acquisition apropriately

```
public PartialViewResult GetDetails ( int id )
{
    List<VoInfoDetail> model = db.VoInfoDetails.Where( m => condition testing id here ).ToList();
    return PartialView("VoDetails", model);
}
```